# Sorting Realm Results in Realm Base Adapter?

Tags: android, list, adapter, realm, radix

In my android app, I am using the realmBaseAdapter to dynamically display data from a realm query. I was wondering if there is any way to sort these results within the adapter so that I can group them based on certain properties.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can :)

You can you build your `RealmResults` like this:

```java
RealmResults<User> results = realm.where(User.class).findAllSorted(
    "name", RealmResults.SORT_ORDER_ASCENDING);
```

or sort the it after build it like:

```
RealmResults<User> result = realm.where(User.class).findAll();
result.sort("age"); // Sort ascending
result.sort("age", RealmResults.SORT_ORDER_DESCENDING);
```

You can also sort by multi fields like:

```
RealmResults<AllTypes> results = testRealm.where(AllTypes.class)
    .findAllSorted(new String[]{"name", "age"},
        new boolean[]{RealmResults.SORT_ORDER_ASCENDING, 
                      RealmResults.SORT_ORDER_ASCENDING});
```

See Doc of [RealmQuery](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html) and [RealmResults](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmResults.html).

You don't have to sort the result every time before using it. Once the results is sorted, it will be sorted even when the database changed and results get updated.

Comment: This doesn't really solve the OP's issue. I believe he needs to sort items after the query has been executed and items need to be resorted by the adapter.

Comment: When you build a `RealmResults` and sort it, Realm will remember the sorting predicate and sort it automatically next time when Realm changes. I think he doesn't have to resort it in the adapter as long as the adapter is suing `RealmResults`/`RealmList` as the data source?